# Full Calender adding anchor in the empty cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using [Adam Shaw's Full Calender](http://fullcalendar.io) on my bookings page.

Now I want to customize this calender in such a way that every empty cell should have a link "Place Booking". Clicking on this anchor should open it in a new tab and takes the date of that cell in the URL.

Here is my code

```
$('.fc-day-number').each(function() {
   var day = parseInt($(this).html());
   $(this).html('<a href="http://www.example.com/booking.php?booking_date='booking date of the cell'" target="_blank">' + day + '</a>');
});
```

For the time being I have placed the anchor on day number of the cell.
But the problem is that the anchors disappear when I change the month from back and forward buttons of the plugin also I am unable to get the date of cell.

I am not an expert in JS any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You only care about monthly view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  viewRender: function(view, $element) {
    $element.find('.fc-day-number').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var match = (/^(\d+)\-(\d+)\-(\d+)$/).exec($this.attr('data-date'));
      var date = new Date(+match[1], +match[2], +match[3]);

      $(this).wrapInner('<a href="http://www.example.com/booking.php?booking_date=' + encodeURIComponent(date.toUTCString()) + '" target="_blank"></a>');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.7.2/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.7.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('body').on('click', '.fc-day-number', function(event) {
   var target = event.target;
   var day = parseInt(target.innerHTML);
   var date = $(target).attr('data-date');
   var url = 'http://www.example.com/booking.php?booking_date=' + date;
   var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
   win.focus();
 })
```

```css
.fc-day-number {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```